# Ruby not stopping execution when using 'return false' in function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, return

I'm struggling with something an am hoping you might have the expertise to help.

I'm coding up an API in Ruby 2.0.0p247 (Rails 3.2.13) with a set of controllers that can call a helper function called send_response which takes a status and optional parameters, and formats it as a proper HTTP response then returns it to the end-user via JSON and then all execution should stop. API calls are protected by a database-backed token.

I'm using `render json: response, :status => response['status'] and return false'` but execution seems to continue regardless of that. Example: API call to add a log entry where I use a bad parameter gets me a JSON response saying bad parameter, but the log entry still gets added.

Source of the 'send_response()' call:

```
def send_response( status, options = {})
  source = options[:source] || nil
  count = options[:count] || -1
  data = options[:data] || nil
  id = options[:id] || -1
  trigger_id = options[:trigger_id] || -1

  response = {}

  case status
    when 'ok', 200
      response['status'] = 200
      response['message'] = 'success'
      response['count'] = count unless count == -1
      response['data'] = data unless data == nil
      response['id'] = id unless id == -1
      response['trigger_id'] = trigger_id unless trigger_id == -1
    when 'bad_request', 400
      response['status'] = 400
      response['message'] = 'error'
      response['data'] = data unless data == nil
    when 'unauthorized', 401
      response['status'] = 401
      response['message'] = 'unauthorized'
      response['data'] = data unless data == nil
    when 'internal_error', 500
      response['status'] = 500
      response['message'] = 'error'
      response['data'] = data unless data == nil
    else
  response['status'] = 500
      response['message'] = 'error'
      response['data'] = 'Invalid send_response() sent.'
   end

  response['source'] = caller[0][/`.*'/][1..-2] if Rails.env.development?

  render json: response, :status => response['status'] and return false
end
```

An example of this function being called by my controller:

```
# Make sure the user is using the correct parameters, otherwise kick 'em out
params.each do |key,value|
  if params_list.include?(key) == false
    send_response 500, data: 'Invalid parameters used!'
  end
end
```

I'm at a complete loss as to why execution isn't ending, and any help would be greatly appreciated to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

--Jayson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` finish execution of current method - in your case if terminates `send_response` method and makes it to return false. You want to return the "parent" method instead:

```
params.each do |key,value|
  if params_list.include?(key) == false
    send_response 500, data: 'Invalid parameters used!' and return false
  end
end
```